# Windows 10 nested environmental variables not working in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, environment-variables

I have an environmental variable called `STEAM` pointing to my Steam installation and a variable `SSE` pointing to a game installed inside it.

[image]

As you can see, the path gets correctly expanded in the Environment Variables dialog window. However if I try to move to `%SSE%` in Windows Explorer, I get an error message:

[image]

Moving to `%STEAM%` works fine though. Is there a way to make nested environmental variables like this work?

Comment: I would assume that the variable resolving is don using the API method `ExpandEnvironmentStringsA` and in it's description there is nothing about nested variables. I think only cmd.exe is capable of resolving nested variables, but this is a feature of the application itself, there is no Windows functionality to achieve that, therefore Windows Explorer does not support nested variables. Have you checked if `cd %sse%` works in `cmd.exe`?

Comment: `The system cannot find the path specified.` Guess it doesn't. Strange that the environment variables window expands the path correctly though. Even stranger is that for me `%STEAM%` is actually an alias for `%DSTEAM%` (I have several variables for my Steam libraries on different drives and `%STEAM%` is the default one on `D:`). So `%STEAM%` is itself already a nested variable, but it's still expanded correctly by Windows Explorer, cmd, etc. It's only when adding extra non-variable pieces to the path (such as in `%SSE%`) that it stops working.